# How to get human readable date with unix time stamp in milliseconds?

Tags: java, datetime

Is there a solution without using the `Date` class which is deprecated, and without having to specify some format like in `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")`, since I just want any readable format? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class isn't deprecated - just many of its constructors/methods are.

You can still use:

```
String text = new Date(millisSinceEpoch).toString();
```

You can't change the string format - it will always use the system default time zone, for example - but it may be enough for you.

Personally I'd still use either `SimpleDateFormat` or better yet `java.time` or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time), but if you really *really* don't want to do that, this might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Caledar class.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
```

Comment: And then what? `Calendar.toString()` doesn't typically give a nice result, IMO.